# iPad in landscape gives wrong width and height

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, width

I am making iOS 7 app where I am finding width and height in landscape mode.

What I have is below in app delegate...

```
NSLog(@"self.window.frame.size.width==%f", self.window.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"self.window.frame.size.height==%f", self.window.frame.size.height);
```

What I was expecting is

```
self.window.frame.size.width==1024
self.window.frame.size.height==768
```

However I get reversed output as

```
self.window.frame.size.width==768
self.window.frame.size.height==1024
```

Note: I have ticked ONLY Landscape Left and Right. I have not selected Potrait & Upside Down.

Any idea why this is happening?

I am doing this on iOS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width and height of the screen and of the window in the screen don't change as the screen orientation changes, they will always be width = 768 and height = 1024 (until Apple makes an iPad with more pixels, like the height of iPhone's has changed).

In that screen window, you have a view controller with a root view. The size of that view will change with the screen orientation.

Comment: Root View of view controller gives me the wrong sizes as in the OP question :(